# Python User Input Within Shell

Tags: python

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I wasn't even sure how to phrase the question to get proper results back from a search engine.

Anyway, I need to create a Python script that uses a text file as input.

Within a Linux shell, a user can type `python samplescript.py NewUser.txt` - The script (`samplescript.py`) will then use "`NewUser.txt`" as input.

My question is, how do I code the script so that it uses "`NewUser.txt`" or another file as the input. Do I use `raw_input()`?

I realize this is probably a novice question but I am rather new to Python so any help is appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: 'The script (samplescript.py) will then use "NewUser.txt" as input.'
That completely depends on the script. Did you mean `python samplescript.py <NewUser.txt`?

Comment: I don't believe so. The way my professor requested we do it is by typing "python samplescript.py NewUser.txt" into the command line and then the script looks at that text file and goes from there.

Comment: Now were talking command line arguments. That'd help to find a solution. You could use `raw_input()` if you use the file contents as standard input (with `python samplescript.py <NewUser.txt`)

Comment: Alright, I understand. What would the syntax look like if using raw_input with NewUser.txt? How do you make it ambiguous so you could enter another file name in there if you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics would be something like the following:

```
import sys
file_path = sys.argv[1]

with open(file_path,"r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Line by line:

1. Import `sys`
2. Get the file path from the **FIRST** argument.
3. Open the file for reading
4. Iterate and print the data.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments passed to the python script are inside `sys.argv`.  The first argument is always the filename of the python script.  Additional arguments come after that.  So in your example, you would get the filename `NewUser.txt` by

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
```

You can then open the file, read the contents, and pass that as input to the rest of your script.  This assumes your passing the *whole* filepath and not just the name of the file, which would only work if your current working directory was the same as the directory of the file you're reading in.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is use `raw_input` to get input from file.

A program uses stdin/stdout for input/output. You can use arrows are for redirection: `>` redirects output to file, `<` redirects input from file.

In general we use:

```
command < input-file
```

and in your case:

```
python samplescript.py < NewUser.txt
```

now when you use `raw_input`, input will be read from `NewUser.txt`